# Compactly supported Dolbeault Cohomology: is this True?

Tags: complex-analysis, homology-cohomology

nLab states that for $D$ the unit disk in $\mathbb C$, the cohomology of the complex
$$ (\Omega_c^{1,\ast}(D),\overline{\partial})$$ is the continuous dual of the space of holomorphic functions $\mathcal O(D)$.

> Is it true that any continuous linear form on $\mathcal O(D)$ can be represented by a form $f dz\wedge d\overline{z}$ with $f$ having compact support?

This result looks really weird to me. What would be the function representing the Delta distribution?

Comment: Could you include a link to this claim? I haven't been able to find it on nLab.

Comment: The $\delta$ distribution at $z_0$ is represented by $f(|z-z_0|) dz \wedge \overline{dz}$ where $f:[0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is any function such that (1) $\int_0^{\infty} 2 \pi r f(r) dr=1$, (2) $f$ is supported close enough to $0$ that $f(|z-z_0)$ is supported in $D$ and (3) $f(|z|)$ is smooth. To see this, note that $\int_D f(|z-z_0|) g(z) dz \wedge \overline{dz} = \int_{r=0}^{\infty} f(r) \int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} g(z_0+r e^{i \theta}) r dr d\theta$. Since $g$ is harmonic, the integral on $\theta$ is $2 \pi g(z_0)$, so we get $g(z_0) \int_{r=0}^{\infty} 2 \pi r f(r) = g(z_0)$.